# How to convert HMHome to javascript for React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm currently working on bridging some HomeKit functions to React Native. I need to be able to convert my array of `HMHome` objects to be interpretable to React Native. I assume I'll need to use `RCTConvert`, but I'm a bit flustered.

I'm subscribing to an event where the user's `HMHome`s are ready to be returned as seen below in `HomeKitPage.js`.

```
this.subscription = RNHomeKitEmitter.addListener(
      'homesReady',
      (homes) => console.log(homes)
    );
```

My `RNHomeKit.m` is emitting the `homesReady` event and returns the list of homes as seen below.

```
- (void)homeManagerDidUpdateHomes:(HMHomeManager *)myHomeManager {
  RCTLog(@"HOMEMANAGERDIDUPDATEHOMES");
  RCTLog(@"PRIMARY HOME:  %@", self.myHomeManager.primaryHome);
  RCTLog(@"MY LIST OF HOMES: %@", self.myHomeManager.homes);

  [self sendEventWithName:@"homesReady" body:@{@"homes": self.myHomeManager.homes}];
}
```

The output for My List of Homes from RCTLog is:

```
MY LIST OF HOMES: (
    "[ name = Matt's Awesome Home, primary : Yes ]"
)
```

So my output seen by the JavaScript console from the EventEmitter is an array where the index is the user's number of homes, and each object is `null` (as expected).

How can I convert this into an array of JSON objects useable by my JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be the ideal way to do it, but it works:

#RNHomeKit.m

```
for (HMHome *home in self.myHomeManager.homes) {
    NSDictionary *homeObject = @{
                   @"name": home.name,
                   @"isPrimary": [NSNumber numberWithBool:home.primary]
                  };
    [homesArray addObject: homeObject];
  };
  
  [self sendEventWithName:@"homesReady" body:@{@"homes": homesArray}];
```

#HomeKitPage.js

```
  RNHomeKit.createHome();
    this.subscription = RNHomeKitEmitter.addListener(
      'homesReady',
      (response) => this.setState({ homes: response.homes })
    );
  }
```